# Keep getting multiple "Required field is missing: valueTranslation" errors while trying to generate a package version with translations

Tags: managed-package, metadata, salesforcedx-cli, translation, bug

When using the `package:version:create` command, I'm getting the following errors:

> ERROR running force:package:version:create:  8-pt_BR: Required field is missing: valueTranslation,1-pt_BR: Required field is missing: valueTranslation,17-pt_BR: Required field is missing: valueTranslation,2-pt_BR: Required field is missing: valueTranslation,3-en_US: Required field is missing: valueTranslation,3-pt_BR: Required field is missing: valueTranslation,38-en_US: Required field is missing: valueTranslation,38-pt_BR: Required field is missing: valueTranslation

The org definition file has the Translation Workbench activated and End User languages too:

```json
{
    "orgName": "App",
    "edition": "Developer",
    "settings": {
        "languageSettings": {
            "enableTranslationWorkbench": true,
            "enableEndUserLanguages": true
        }
    },
    "language": "en_US"
}
```

Usually, the translation is separated into multiple files, such as the "globalValueSetTranslation", the ones on the "objectTranslations" folder and the ones inside the "standardValueSetTranslations" folder.

Why is this error happening, as I have translated everything with the Translation Workbench on my scratch org?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out while writing this question. Hopefully this helps anyone with the same issue today (API 50.0).

---

In this case, Salesforce generated those translation files in the error message in the standardValueSetTranslations folder. They were named as `{number}-pt_BR.standardValueSetTranslation-meta.xml`.

Those numbers were supposed to be replaced by a standard field API name value, such as `AccountType`, for the account's standard "type" field.

To solve this issue:

1. You can safely remove those files from your project.
2. To retrieve the actual translations, you can use the `retrieve` command (below).

`sfdx force:source:retrieve -m StandardValueSetTranslation`

After that, I was able to successfully generate a new package version for my app.